# How to configure debian/rules file for packaging with CDBS and Cmake, Qt5 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, compiling, qt5, cmake

this is the first time I ask here.
Recently I played packaging --a new thing for me-- in Launchpad.
I tried compiling *Sigil* 0.7.4 for Ubuntu Precise. The source code had to be compiled with Qt5, while by default Precise only provide Qt4. So I used [“Ubuntu SDK team”](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ppa) for the build dependencies.
I did the local building with `bzr` in Trusty and everything seems to work properly. But the build in the Launchpad stuck with an error. [Have a look at the log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/170491005/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.sigil_0.7.4-1ppa1~precise1.4_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz).

The `debian/rules` file contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk
include /usr/share/cdbs/1/class/cmake.mk

DEB_CMAKE_EXTRA_FLAGS += -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/qmake
```

According to the build log, the parameter for Cmake extra flags is working. But why it still gave an error? Where is qt5-qmake located, so that it stop giving error?

Thanks in advanced.

**Edit**
For those who have the same problem, you might have been googling around to solve. I give more details about the error:

```
   CMake Warning at src/Sigil/CMakeLists.txt:38 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


  CMake Error at src/Sigil/CMakeLists.txt:454 (qt5_wrap_ui):
  Unknown CMake command "qt5_wrap_ui".
```

Comment: Did you set that PPA as a build dependency?

Comment: Yes, I'vet set Ubuntu SDK Team PPA as my PPA's build dependency.

Comment: The error here is not the flag or `qmake`; the error is that `cmake` needs to verify that Qt5 is available, so it looks for a file called Qt5Config.cmake or qt5-config.cmake. However, it can't find these files. However, Qt5 does provide cmake files, but you need to spcify the modules you need (see [this](http://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5/) page for the syntax).

Comment: You're right, I might have forgot that this version of Sigil should be compiled by Qt 5.1+, otherwise Ubuntu SDK team only provide Qt 5.0.2.

Comment: I was wrong with my last comment. Even after I provided Qt 5.2.1 as build dependency, the build process was still giving the same error. [The latest build log](https://launchpad.net/~bedouin/+archive/ppa/+build/5845981/+files/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.sigil_0.7.4-1ppa1~precise1.6_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz). This starts driving me mad, duh!

Comment: Open up the CMakeLists.txt file, and search for the string "Qt5" (it should be on or near line 38). It should be inside a find_package call. That line is causing (half of) the problem because the method for detecting Qt libraries has changed with Qt5. See the link I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, I have read the post you gave, and yes actually in the CMakeLists.txt is still like the method for Qt4. But that's just working on building in Trusty, which has the same Qt version (5.2.1), I'll try to edit it first. Hope it works.

Comment: On another note, you might be interested in using a clean Precise (or any version) chroot to build packages instead of uploading to Launchpad. `pbuilder` and `sbuild` are two such tools that can help you in this.

Comment: Thanks for your recommends, but those might not suitable for me as my internet connection is limited :)