# What package should I include as build-depend based on this error

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging, launchpad

Previously, I've asked about **debian/rules** additional build flag of CMake for packaging in Launchpad. [The question is here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438280/how-to-configure-debian-rules-file-for-packaging-with-cdbs-and-cmake-qt5-on-ubu)

Now I managed to accomplish that by changing that **debian/rules**. And I managed to do `bzr builddeb -- -us -uc` in my local computer. I don't know exactly what packages to be included as build-depend in the clean machine. The latest error log in Launchpad build system is like this:

```
CMake Error at /opt/qt52/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:16 (message):
  Failed to find "GL" in "" with CMAKE_CXX_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE
  "i386-linux-gnu".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/qt52/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:50 (_qt5gui_find_extra_libs)
  /opt/qt52/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:143 (include)
  /opt/qt52/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake:88 (find_package)
  /opt/qt52/lib/cmake/Qt5Svg/Qt5SvgConfig.cmake:88 (find_package)
  /opt/qt52/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package)
  src/Sigil/CMakeLists.txt:38 (find_package)
```

Any idea?

**Edit:**
Okay, no one answered. But fortunately, I've found that `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libglu1-mesa-dev` are what I'm looking for.

And the building seems to go successfully: <strike>here</strike>

<strike>But, hold on, something is still missing.</strike>

**Edit 2:**
Eventually, it is successfully built. [This is the build log](https://launchpad.net/~bedouin/+archive/ppa/+build/5854923/+files/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.sigil_0.7.4-1ppa1~precise5_UPLOADING.txt.gz)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Qt 5.2 builds, you are installing the libraries to /opt/qt52. This isn't the standard place for libraries, and therefore the libraries are not found by `shlibdeps` (and also probably wouldn't run on a user's computer because there is no RPATH specified). Instead, you should install libraries to /usr/lib, which is the standard place in Precise.

Also, typically, library packages are split into three packages: a package that only contains the runtime library (what the user would need just to use the library in an application), a development package (what a developer would need, which includes the headers and the development library symlink), and a debug package. Your current structure has the runtime package and the development package combined, which means that users will have to install more stuff than necessary. You might want to look into splitting that package (see a [sample debian directory](http://sources.debian.net/src/qtbase-opensource-src/5.2.1%2Bdfsg-3) that Debian uses for Qt 5.2.1; note that the -dev package files are specified in the qtbase5-dev.install-common file).

Comment: I've rebuilt it again, and I added LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /opt/qt52/lib. Hope it works. Actually I only use https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/opt-qt521 as PPA Dependencies and I don't have any intention to build Qt5 by my own. Perhaps I will build Sigil in my local computer with Qt5 from qt-project.org. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the recent build [failures](https://launchpad.net/~bedouin/+archive/ppa/+builds?build_text=&build_state=all) that you got in your ppa you're depending on Qt5 packages that are not available for precise (such as `libqt5widgets5`).

I'd suggest to add a new ppa dependency to your own ppa, the **ubuntu-sdk-team stable** ppa:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ppa

Go to [this page](https://launchpad.net/~bedouin/+archive/ppa/+edit-dependencies) to add it.

Comment: I've used it before, and the build was failed, too. I likely forgot to add -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH then. Actually I want Qt 5.2 provided by https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/opt-qt521 to be installed if I installed Precise, because I prefer the newer version. Thanks.