# Launchpad invoking 64-bit programme in 32-bit build environment

Tags: packaging, launchpad

I am trying to package a Qt programme for Trusty. I have successfully built the package in my system and uploaded it to a PPA. The `control` file includes the following:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0), cdbs, libpq-dev, libxml2-dev, clang, qt5-qmake, qt5-default, qttools5-dev-tools, qt5-image-formats-plugins
```

The Launchpad [log file](https://launchpad.net/~luis-de-sousa/+archive/ubuntu/modelling/+build/8963272/+files/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-i386.pgmodeler_0.8.2-beta-1ubuntu7_BUILDING.txt.gz) appears to show that `qt5-make` is in fact installed in the build system. However, the compilation is issuing this error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile pgmodeler.pro
make[1]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake: Command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile] Error 127
make[1]: Failed to remake makefile `Makefile'.
```

Why is the 64-bit version of `qmake` being invoked instead of the 32-bit?

Comment: Could be related http://askubuntu.com/questions/438280/how-to-configure-debian-rules-file-for-packaging-with-cdbs-and-cmake-qt5-on-ubu

Comment: I am certainly learning that there is a long hard road to package a Qt programme for Ubuntu, but that earlier question seems to be unrelated.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa You got able to solve this?

Comment: No, I did not. I eventually quit trying to package software for Ubuntu. If you use Python, [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org) is considerably easier and platform independent.